# Selenium problem handling drop down using data driven approach

Tags: selenium

I want to select a value from a drop down and I am sending data into the drop down from Excel. When I inspected the element there is an id locator which remains the same and the value is changing as the selected value.

If I select globle then id="ABC"> globle  If I select any other then globle will change to that. I used static and dynamic both ways but every time multiple errors.

Comment: please read [mcve] and edit your question accordingly, what error stack trace you getting? where is your code trials? how the element html structure looks like? etc .. things required to reproduce/debug the problem, from henceforth remember to add the necessary details in order to get possible helpful responses

Answer (score 0):

This is hard without examples of the DOM you're working with and your code/stack traces, but maybe I can point you in the right direction.

Depending on the website, you'll often see id's change when you interact with different elements. I'm not sure which language you're using, but the method will be the same here regardless. Build an XPath with the id, value, or text that you are expecting the option value to contain. With Selenium, you often cannot interact with elements that are not displayed in the browser, so you must click on the dropdown button first before attempting to click on the option element in question.

If you have any problems with the above approach, check your XPath first, and ensure that you're actually targeting the right element.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you fetch all elements of list and stored in List of WebElement then iterate that list with foreach loop and take out each element one by one and fetch text of that and compare it with your expected text from excel. Then, where it is matching with your expected text click on that element. Below is snippet:

public void method(String excelvalue){

List lstele = driver.findElements(--your locator--);

for(WebElement e : lstele){

if((e.getText()).equals(excelvalue)){
e.click();
break;  //don't forget to break the loop once you got your desired element
}

}
}

Comment: public void filldata() throws IOException, InterruptedException{ 
DataDriven d = new DataDriven(driver);
ArrayList<String> data=d.getData("Ingestion");
WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,30);wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='progressDiv']/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div"))).click();
  Thread.sleep(3000);
   driver.findElement(Division1).sendKeys("Global Markets");
    //driver.findElement(Bunit).sendKeys(data.get(2));
Got error :  ElementNotInteractableException: It worked fine till Click

Comment: HTML Code :<div class="Select design2-select btn-group has-value is-searchable Select--single"><div class="Select-control" style="width: 100%; height: 30px; font-size: 15px; -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-4--value"><div class="Select-value"><span class="Select-value-label" id="react-select-4--value-item" role="option" aria-selected="true">ECMS Test</span></div><div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;"><style>input#unitdivision::-ms-clear {display: none;}</style><input id="unitdivision" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false"